# change not working jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to show change value in a `div` but not working. Here is a example :

```js
button_up=document.getElementById('up');
button_down=document.getElementById('down');

button_up.onclick=function() {setQuantity('up');}
button_down.onclick=function() {setQuantity('down');}

quantity = document.getElementById('quantity');

function setQuantity(upordown) {

    if (quantity.value > 1) {
        if (upordown == 'up'){++quantity.value;}
        else if (upordown == 'down'){--quantity.value;}}
    else if (quantity.value == 1) {
        if (upordown == 'up'){++quantity.value;}}
    else
        {quantity.value=1;}

}

$('.order-option input[type=\'text\']').change(function(){
           $('.show').text($('#quantity').val())   
         });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="order-option">Quantity: <span id="quantity-field">
        <button id="down">-</button>
        <input type="text" id="quantity" value="1">
        <button id="up">+</button>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="show"></div>
```

Comment: works just fine when you do something that would trigger a change event. *hint hint*

Comment: You seem to be mixing a lot of js with jquery.  Try to maintain some sort of consistency, I know document.getElementById works but since you're using jquery why not just $("#quantity") ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change event wont be invoked when you are trying to do with jquery, it will be triggered only when you force change the value by mouse or keyboard... So you need to trigger the change event while setting the quantity as  per functionality.

```
var button_up=document.getElementById('up');
var button_down=document.getElementById('down');

button_up.onclick=function() {setQuantity('up');}
button_down.onclick=function() {setQuantity('down');}

var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity');
var $targetInput = $('.order-option input[type=\'text\']');
function setQuantity(upordown) {

    if (quantity.value > 1) {
        if (upordown == 'up'){++quantity.value;}
        else if (upordown == 'down'){--quantity.value;}}
    else if (quantity.value == 1) {
        if (upordown == 'up'){++quantity.value;}}
    else
        {quantity.value=1;}
   $targetInput.trigger('change');
}

$targetInput.change(function(){
    $('.show').text($('#quantity').val())   ;
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your buttons for plus and minus should handle a click event to signal a change.  As an example if you go directly into the input field and enter a number and lose focus you'll see your div get the update.  You could do something as follows:

First assign a class to both buttons, same class name:

```
<button class="movingOnUpOrDown" id="down">-</button>
<button class="movingOnUpOrDown" id="up">-</button>
```

Then handle the event at the class level:

```
$(".movingOnUpOrDown").click(function(){
   $('.show').text($('#quantity').val()); 
});
```

You may want to refactor this such as calling a method to getValue since you already have a set.  In the button click event you could call the `setValue()` function and then right after it to `getValue()` and this function would simply return your quantity.

This is not all tested, but should have you thinking about other possibilities.

Comment: Yes added, set both buttons to have a class name, then handle the click event.

Answer (score 0):

Small changes in your `setQuantity` function

```
function setQuantity(upordown) {    
    if (quantity.value > 1) {
        if (upordown == 'up'){++quantity.value;}
        else if (upordown == 'down'){--quantity.value;}}
    else if (quantity.value == 1) {
        if (upordown == 'up'){++quantity.value;}}
    else{
         quantity.value=1;
    }   
    $('.show').html(quantity.value);
}
```

You don't need this

```
$('.order-option input[type=\'text\']').change(function(){
           $('.show').text($('#quantity').val())   
         });
```

Comment: This is another possibility but I think set should only set the value, another method should be called for getting said value.

Comment: This is not my question

Comment: @MAHAR what is your question. then? You wanted to show the text in the div

Comment: Puting all together with OP's original code I see lots of `click` event.

Comment: As an alternative to creating two functions but making the code a bit cleaner as @JonH suggests, you could rename the function `Quantity` and as a first line check `if(upordown) { ... } else { $('.show').html(quantity.value); }`. It would operate more like an `observable` in an MVVM style framework would then where calling `Quantity();` would get the value and calling `Quantity('down');` would set the value. Ultimately though, two separate functions would be cleaner...

Comment: @jonju - That is why I posted he / she should refactor.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the code in the same order as you have posted then it won't work.

Usually the mark goes first as it must be downloaded on the browser first before Javascript can work with it.

So it will be

HTML
Javascript libraries references such as jQuery
and then custom JavaScript.

I ran your code and straight got an error in the Console that you cannot define onclick on null. your buttons are null when the javascript is executing as it didn't wait for the html to be downloaded.

in jQuery you can use something like document.ready() to wait for the html(DOM) to be downloaded before you execute your code.

Try the reorganisation of code and wrap your code in document.ready and also keep an eye on the Developer Tools (Console) in any modern browser.

If that doesn't help then come back here again.

---

I have just edited your code and I can get text from quantity input field to be displayed in the show div with minor change.

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="order-option">Quantity: <span id="quantity-field">
        <button id="down">-</button>
        <input type="text" id="quantity" value="1">
        <button id="up">+</button>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="show"></div>
</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(function(){
button_up=document.getElementById('up');
button_down=document.getElementById('down');

button_up.onclick=function() {setQuantity('up');}
button_down.onclick=function() {setQuantity('down');}

quantity = document.getElementById('quantity');

function setQuantity(upordown) {

    if (quantity.value > 1) {
        if (upordown == 'up'){++quantity.value;   $('.show').text($('#quantity').val())   ;}
        else if (upordown == 'down'){--quantity.value;}}
    else if (quantity.value == 1) {
        if (upordown == 'up'){++quantity.value;}}
    else
        {quantity.value=1;}

}

$('.order-option input[type=\'text\']').change(function(){
           $('.show').text($('#quantity').val())   
         });
         });
 </script>
```

As quantity input is not getting changed physically, the onchange event is not going to be fired. If you want to test it then put your cursor in the quantity input field and type something there and then click somewhere else in the screen and you will see that whatever you typed in quantity box will be displayed in the show div. this is because you changed the input field and moved the focus.

So I would suggest you update the show div at the same time when you are updating the quantity input field (I have added one example of it in my code above) and remove the onchange event which won't work.